# Switch case for string using keyfromString function

Tags: c

**I have use this code to use switch case for a string**

```
#define BADKEY -1
#define b 1
#define s 2
#define r 3
#define p 4

typedef struct { char *key; int val; } t_symstruct;

static t_symstruct lookuptable[] = {
{"b",b},{"s",s},{"r",r,{"p",p}
 };

#define NKEYS (sizeof(lookuptable)/sizeof(t_symstruct))

int main () {
```

**what is a mistake here?**

```
 int keyfromstring(char *key)
 {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i < NKEYS; i++) {
         if (strcmp(lookuptable[i].key, key) == 0)
            return lookuptable[i].val;
         }
    return BADKEY;
 }
```

**switch case in c**

```
switch (keyfromstring(field1))
{
     case b :
     printf(" is b\n" );
     break;

     case s :
     printf("is s\n" );
     break;

     case r :
     printf(" is r\n" );
     break;

     case ps:
     printf("is p\n" );
     break;

     case BADKEY:
     printf("Case: BADKEY \n");
     break;

     default://case if nothing
     printf("Case: nothing happen\n"); 
}
```

**I got this message error segmentation fault(core dumped) 
after printing some lines correctly,so please what can be the error here?

Comment: Is case ps: a typo?

Comment: You must add the entire [mcve] into your question.

Comment: char* field1 = strtok(line,","); where line reading lines from file line by line

Answer (score 0):

check the field1 before passing to the function there could be some issue with that. I am not seeing any error here . plus you did not clearly mention when it will crash

if you got the error segmentation fault(core dumped) once at the end of printing the switch case .you could be getting null at the end 
check if feild1 is null .

Answer (score 0):

The `lookuptable` has typos, it should like:

```
static t_symstruct lookuptable[] = {
    {"b",b}, {"s",s}, {"r",r},  {"p",p}
};
```

Your original version will not even compile. The testing program is presented below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BADKEY -1
#define b 1
#define s 2
#define r 3
#define p 4

typedef struct {
    char *key;
    int val;
} t_symstruct;

static t_symstruct lookuptable[] = {
    {"b",b}, {"s",s}, {"r",r},  {"p",p}
};

#define NKEYS (sizeof(lookuptable)/sizeof(t_symstruct))

int keyfromstring(char *key)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < NKEYS; i++) {
        if (strcmp(lookuptable[i].key, key) == 0)
            return lookuptable[i].val;
    }
    return BADKEY;
}

int main (void) {

    char * arr[] = { "b","s","r", "p", "!", NULL} ;
    int i;

    for (i =0; arr[i] !=NULL; i++)
    {   
        switch (keyfromstring(arr[i]))
        {
        case b :
            printf("%s is b\n", arr[i] );
            break;

        case s :
            printf("%s is s\n", arr[i] );
            break;

        case r :
            printf("%s is r\n", arr[i] );
            break;

        case p:
            printf("%s is p\n", arr[i] );
            break;

        case BADKEY:
            printf("Case: BADKEY: %s \n",  arr[i] );
            break;

        default://case if nothing
            printf("Case: nothing happen\n");
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
b is b                                                                                                                                           
s is s                                                                                                                                           
r is r                                                                                                                                           
p is p                                                                                                                                           
Case: BADKEY: !
```